# MySQL connectionstate doesn't work as expected

Tags: mysql, vb.net, database-connection

I have form application written in vb.net. It uses MySqlClient:

```vb
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class frmTest
Dim AConn As MySqlConnection
Dim errMsg as String = ""

Sub New()
    Try
        'Opens connection as forms open and keep it open
        If checkConn() = False Then Throw New Exception(ErrMsg)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Function checkConn() As Boolean
    Try
        'if connection is not initiated then initiate
        If IsNothing(AConn) Then AConn = New MySqlConnection(ConnSTR)

        'if connectionstate is any other than "open", reconnect  
        If AConn.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
            closeConn()
            AConn.Open()
        End If

        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        ErrMsg = ex.Message
        Return False
    End Try
End Function

Sub closeConn()
    Try
        AConn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
            Button2.Click
    Try
        If checkConn() = False then Throw New Exception(errMsg)
        Dim cmdCheck As New MySqlCommand("show databases;", AConn)
        cmdCheck.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex as Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

Now, when I open form it works fine. Connection opens, and by clicking I get result. Then, I leave form idle for 10 minutes and click button2 again. 
It passes "checkConn" without error, and it says connectionstate is "open", but, when it comes to line "cmdCheck.ExecuteNonQuery()" exception throws: "Fatal error...". The problem is that connection state (in checkConn()) reports Connection.Open, althought it's not (I checked on server - it is closed because of period of inactivity). 
Is there a better way to check connection state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not the first person that I've seen using a method like that.  Don't.  It's bad.  Simply create and destroy connection objects as and where you need them.  Get rid of the `AConn` field and that `checkConn` method and do it like this:

```vb
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Try
        Using AConn As New MySqlConnection(ConnSTR)
            Dim cmdCheck As New MySqlCommand("show databases;", AConn)
            AConn.Open()
            cmdCheck.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    Catch ex as Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

There are times that it is a good idea to use fields to hold references to ADO.NET objects.  This is not one of those times.  Creating ADO.NET objects as required should be the default.

An ADO.NET connection object exists at a high level, with the actual database connection existing at a lower level.  ADO.NET connections are specifically intended to be created when they're needed, opened as late as possible and closed as early as possible.  ADO.NET manages the underlying database connection for you.  If you have an ADO.NET connection object open for 10 minutes without it having data passing over it most of that time, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Thanks for prompt answer. Your code misses "Finally aconn.close", and I tried that already. Bad thing with this approach is that "connection.close" doesn't necessarily close connection on server (there's explanation for this that mentions connection pool, but it's another topic), so you end up with huge number of "IDLE" connections on server.

Comment: Probably this is the effect of connection pooling. It is a feature you really need on your client app. See more how to control it at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connection-pooling.html

Comment: My code doesn't miss a `Close` call on the connection at all. Because the connection object is created with a `Using` statement, it is implicitly disposed at the `End Using` line.  That implicitly closes the connection.  As suggested, you ought to read up on connection pooling. The way it is supposed to work is that the first time you create an ADO.NET connection object, a low-level database connection is opened. Subsequent ADO.NET connections with the same connection string use that same low-level connection It times out and closes after a period of time and another is opened later if needed.

Comment: I use a Using...End Using block for the command object as well. (and the reader, if there is one) Is this correct @jmcilhinney?

Comment: @Mary, I would definitely do so for a data reader and you can for a command too but there isn't actually any point. A command object has a Dispose method by virtue of inheriting Component. If you're not using it in that capacity, i.e. adding it to a form in the designer, there's not actually anything to dispose. It won't hurt but it won't help either.

Comment: Thanks to all. @jmcilhinney is absolutely right. Actually, I was using open/close/dispose (similar to using/end using) before this and, end up with "too many connections" on server. That's why I tried this approach (with one connection, no matter it stays unused for long time). Finally, I found it wasn't problem with open/close/dispose, but I made stupid mistake by creating new "AConn" object every time I need it, instead of instantiating it on application level.